# How do you make a ray reflection like a ping-pong ball? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Vector2 _vector;
[SerializeField] private int _reflectionCount;
[SerializeField] private float _distance;

private void Update()
{
    Vector2[] points = GetReflectionPoints(transform.position, _vector, _reflectionCount, _distance, Physics2D.AllLayers);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 == points.Length)
            break;

        Debug.DrawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], Color.red);
    }
}

public static Vector2[] GetReflectionPoints(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 vector, int reflectionCount, float distance, int layerMask)
{
    List<Vector2> points = new(reflectionCount);

    vector.Normalize();
    points.Add(currentPosition);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < reflectionCount; i++)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(currentPosition, vector, distance, layerMask);
        points.Add(hit.point);
        vector = Vector2.Reflect(vector, -hit.normal);
    }

    return points.ToArray();
}
```

}

Here's my code, and here's the result:
[image]

The red color is the trajectory I got, and the green is the trajectory I want. I watched many videos on this topic and all of them used either `Rigidbody2D.velocity` or loops. Is there any other way to do this (for example, through a dot product)?

Comment: The solution lies in your drawing, you want that direction to be perpendicular to the incoming direction. Rotate that direction instead of using hit surface normal.

Comment: @aybe yes, it works, but very often I get a vector returned along the collider, and it looks like the character is stuck to the wall and crawling up

Comment: Errors tend to quickly sum up, I would first assert that player and its direction is 100% reliable no matter how close it is to a wall. Once done, rotating the vector will be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have never updated the origin of the ray.

```
vector = Vector2.Reflect(vector, -hit.normal);
currentPosition = hit.point * vector * 0.01f; // +++
```

[image: Result screenshot]

The entire method

```
public static Vector2[] GetReflectionPoints(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 vector, int reflectionCount, float distance, int layerMask)
{
    List<Vector2> points = new(reflectionCount);

    vector.Normalize();
    points.Add(currentPosition);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < reflectionCount; i++)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(currentPosition, vector, distance, layerMask);
        points.Add(hit.point);
        vector = Vector2.Reflect(vector, -hit.normal);
        currentPosition = hit.point * vector * 0.01f; // +++
    }

    return points.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: no man, everything started work worse, and the ray is not reflected at all

Comment: I absolutely still need to do something with the reflection code itself

Comment: I tried it and the problem should be that the reflected ray collided with the collider of the first collision again, so I tried to move the origin of the second raycast forward a bit along the ray.

Comment: Oh, man, I'm almost back to the result that was in the picture in the question. I was trying to rotate the vector 90 degrees, looking at the angle at which it came in: 
`float d = Mathf.Sign(UnitVector.VectorToDeg180(vector)); 
vector = RotateVector(vector, 90f * d);
currentPosition = hit.point * vector * 0.01f;`
 but it looked pretty strange from different angles, except for the half centers of the walls.

Could you please update your answer and show me the entire code related to reflections?

Comment: It's just the code from your question besides the additional annotated line.